# reinstalling magento 2 extension

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have a **magento 2** extension installed **via ftp**. It resides in magento `root/app/code`. What is the best way to completely re-install the extension? What are the steps to do it? I could not find a definite guide online...

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it manually:

remove the folder **app/code/Vendor/Module**

drop module tables from database

remove the config settings.

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'
```

remove the module **Vendor_Module** from **app/etc/config.php**

remove the module **Vendor_Module** from table **setup_module**

```
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='Vendor_Module'
```

At last add extension again in **app/code** folder and run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Quick question, why do I need to delete all the configs? Is it necessary?

Comment: Not necessary. Optional.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your extension entry from `setup_module` table also remove your tables which are created by extension script.

After that below command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```